How influx store tag in db?
I'm new to influx and just started to study it, and at the moment I'm worried about one question to which I can't find an affirmative answer - how does influx save tags, that is, it indexes them, but I have a fear that it writes to a line up to a point, that is, if I I will record 20k points every 5 minutes, something like this:
measurement, region=region1,city=city1 value=0.6 time...
measurement, region=region1,city=city2 value=0.9 time...
measurement, region=region2,city=city3 value=0.5 time...

So, will influx store these texts region1, city1, etc. for each point, or will it group data by indexes to make them easier, like:
measurement, tag[region=region1,city=city1]
     time=..., value=0.6
     time=..., value=0.8
     time=..., value=0.9
     ...
measurement, tag[region=region1,city=city2]
     time=..., value=0.9
     time=..., value=0.7
     time=..., value=0.4
     ...
...

will it store them in the same form as they were recorded, like:
measurement, region=region1,city=city2 value=0.9 time...
measurement, region=region2,city=city3 value=0.5 time...

I ask this with the intention of finding out how many months such measurements can take, that is, conditionally, if it stores as I described line by line, then it turns out that we have the same text for each record, which will take up space on the SSD
